# How to get active workspace

Tags: python, workspaces

I would like to know in which workspace I am. Based on this info I need to do other things, but I did not find any solution for this. This one `bpy.ops.workspace` shows all options, but as I said I did not find anything like this which will show only the workspace I currently use.

Comment: That should be `bpy.context.workspace`. Context is where you will always find your "active/selected" stuff because it's the stuff that pertains to your interaction with blender in the current specific "context". `bpy.data` is where everything resides, not just the currently selected stuff, `bpy.ops` is for functions you perform on objects and data, etc.

Read up on [this section](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html) of the API to drill into your head what resides where in each specific context.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot :)